# VBA, If not empty execute for row

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

In my script I got the following line.

```
.Range(.Cells(1, "GP"), .Cells(last, "GP")).FormulaR1C1 = "=ISOWEEKNUM(RC" & i & ")"
```

However, for an empty row this writes "52" (Since that's the week for an empty date).
Is there a way I can write nothing if the line is empty?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps use this as your formula:

```
"=IF(RC" & i & "="""","""",ISOWEEKNUM(RC" & i & "))"
```

Comment: that or  `=IF(ISBLANK(RC" & i & "),"""",ISOWEEKNUM(RC" & i & "))"`

Comment: "=IF(RC" & i & "="<>""","""",ISOWEEKNUM(RC" & i & "))"

Apparently worked

Comment: No way that exact formula could have worked, unless you have a typo in your comment. Plus that logic doesn't match your description.

Comment: "=IF(RC" & i & "<>"""",ISOWEEKNUM(RC" & i & "),"""")"

to be exact worked

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving it with:

```
"=IF(RC" & i & "<>"""",ISOWEEKNUM(RC" & i & "),"""")" to be exact worked
```